# how to know the check box value of a particular row of a listview

Tags: java, android, checkbox

hey how can i know that the below checkbox when clicked is from which row of the list.
is there any way of knowing that. Every time yo is returning false which is its default value.

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                        callBlockOptions callBlockOptions = (callBlockOptions) cb.getTag();

                        callBlockOptions.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );

                        String yo;

                        if(callBlockOptions.getPosition()=="0")
                        {
                            callBlockOptions.setAllCalls();
                        }


                        if(callBlockOptions.getAllCalls() ==true)
                            yo="true";
                        else
                            yo="false";

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), callBlockOptions.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });        
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your code, one thing you might want to try is setting listeners for the individual children within the ListView. You could do something like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
int count = listView.getChildCount();
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
{
    Class<? extends View> c = listView.getChildAt(x).getClass();
    if (c == CheckBox.class)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)(listView.getChildAt(x));
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoutButton, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                callBlockOptions.isChecked = isChecked;
            }
        });
    }
    else if (c == TextView.class)
    {
        TextView textView = (TextView)(listView.getChildAt(x));
        textView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView tView, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                callBlockOptions.name = tView.getText().toString();
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
```

You probably want your other class to be like this:

```
public class callBlockOptions {
     public static String name;
     public static Boolean isChecked;
}
```

Then you can get and set name and isChecked like this:

```
callBlockOptions.isChecked = false;
Boolean boolVal = callBlockOptions.isChecked;
```

Comment: You're listening for events on the ListView. It sounds to me like you're interested in the items within the ListView such as the CheckBox and TextView.

Comment: Also, if you want your variables from the class callBlockOptions to be static, you will want the class variables to be static, not the class itself. Then you can get and set them with callBlockOptions.variableName without having to instantiate a callBlockOptions object.

Comment: hey thanks for your help! i have one last query, in the following code how can i know my checkbox belongs to which list row.

Comment: You should be able to use int x from the for loop. If that works out for you please make sure you up vote my answer and accept the answer by clicking the gray check box :).

Comment: Well, I don't remember what your methods were doing with that callBlockOptions class. Is it not working for you? Also, you probably want to be using setOnCheckedChangeListener for the ComboBox. Anyways, you should be able to figure it out from here :).